# is 'Truth be told' informal?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> **Truth be told**, I do not like writing.

I know that some idioms are informal, but is this one also considered informal? I want to use it in my essay.

Comment: If it's a formal essay, why include it at all? Just say: _I do not like writing._ The reader will assume you are being truthful.

Answer (score 1):

**Truth be told** is conversational.  It is a set phrase. It means, "to speak truthfully".

> Truth be told, I've always thought that composer is vastly overrated.
>
> Truth be told, I ate the last piece of pie.
>
> Truth be told, the lower-priced product is identical. It is made to the same specifications at the same facility, but a different label is put on it.
>
> Truth be told, they're all Shamu.